# "Delete item" button inside a SWT Combo

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Take a look at the image below:

[image]

Is it possible to add a small delete button beside each item in the Combo?

This will perform deletion of the item from the item list in Combo.

Comment: SWT does not have `ComboBox` are you asking about the SWT `Combo` or the JavaFX `ComboBox`?

Comment: You are right. I want to use SWT Combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SWT `Combo` control only displays simple lines of text, buttons and other controls are not possible.

You might be able to use the Eclipse Nebula [TableCombo](https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php) control which displays a table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are looking for is possible. You can have multi-column combo boxes sure but they are still representation of same data and each row generates an event rather than column.